# Django get_context_data error

Tags: django, python-3.x

i'm  trying to create a custom get_context_data, but i'm getting the error **get_context_data() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**, and I don't know why

can someone help me?, why i'm getting this error?, and how i can solve it?

thanks in advance

```
class JobDetail(DetailView):
    model = Job
    template_name = 'employer/job_detail.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(JobDetail, self).get_context_data(kwargs)

        job = Job.objects.all()

        sign_job = False
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            get_job = SignJob.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, job=job) # TODO:look at how to get the job the right way
            if self.request.method == 'POST':
                SignJob.objects.create(user=self.request.user, job=job)
            sign_job = get_job.exists()

        context['sign_job'] = sign_job
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to depack the `kwargs` arguments:

```
context = super(JobDetail, self).get_context_data(kwargs)
```

Should be:

```
context = super(JobDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Also, just a small suggestion, you can rewrite your `get_context_data` method like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    job = Job.objects.all()

    sign_job = False
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        get_job = SignJob.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, job=job) # TODO:look at how to get the job the right way
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            SignJob.objects.create(user=self.request.user, job=job)
        sign_job = get_job.exists()

    return super(JobDetail, self).get_context_data(
        sign_job=sign_job,
        **kwargs
    )
```